# Need to change the cell colours exactly as matched in other excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, colors

I have two excel files with similar set of data in columns. One sheet has specific colours in the data and the other sheet has some values. I need to copy exact colours to the exact matching cells.
Example: In Column B1 I have a number data. In front of the cell B1, In the same row there is set of data. In the other sheet, the set of data that is in the B1 cell is given in the M5 cell, and in front of it is the column given with colours in the cells. I need to paste the same colour given in M5 cell to the range of B1 cell.

Comment: What is stopping you formatting the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell
do Copy
select the receiving cell
do "Paste special..." command
a dialog opens and you can select what to paste, in your case the format.

Note: I dont know exactly where is the command because I not use the new interface of Excel 2010...